# Passing two values to a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I've written a stored procedure which is called on a link which provides a date value every time and @cg is NULL that time to filter the result on a particular date.

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Get_Mydata]
        @cg = NULL,
        @tosearch = '15-05-2014'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

And after first execution of the stored procedure, it gives some results and using same stored procedure.

I need to filter result by passing below parameter so this time `@cg` is NOT NULL.

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Get_Mydata]
        @cg = 'CUSTOMER NAME',
        @tosearch = 'manish'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I'm not able to figure how should I create a dynamic where clause and add it to existing query as well as how to pass value to same parameter which already been passed as date.

More like first getting results for a particular date and then applying like filter on that result. I cannot pass different parameter that's Front end developers requirement.

This is my stored procedure and table data here.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb917

```
create proc Get_Mydata
(
   @cg         varchar(50),
   @tosearch   varchar(50)
)
as
begin
   set nocount on

   declare @sqlquery nvarchar(max)

   set @sqlquery = N'select q_no, trandate, cust_name from testsp where CONVERT(Date, trandate, 103)  = CONVERT(Date, ''' + @tosearch + ''' ,103)';


   create table #temp1
   (
      q_no int,
      trandate datetime,
      cust_name varchar(50)
   )

   insert into #temp1(q_no, trandate, cust_name)
     exec (@sqlquery)

   select * from #temp1 as T;

   set nocount off
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have understood is that you want stored procedure to filter results on Date column when you pass null to `@cg` param and you want to filter results on Cust_name when you pass string `'Cust_Name'` to your @Cg Param.

It should be fairly simple, But in any case you do not need a temp table to get the results back its just an over kill of a fairly simple query.

I would do something like this....

Pass the column name to `@ColumnName` Parameter, and your value to `@tosearch` parameter. It will build the query depending on what values you pass.

Make sure when you pass a value(Column Name) to `@ColumnName`.

```
create proc Get_Mydata
(
   @ColumnName varchar(50),
   @tosearch   varchar(50)
)
as
begin
   set nocount on;

   declare @sqlquery nvarchar(max);

   set @sqlquery = N' select q_no, trandate, cust_name '  
                 + N' from testsp ' 
                 + N' where ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName)  + N' = '
                 + CASE 
                       WHEN @ColumnName = 'trandate' 
                           THEN  N' CAST(@tosearch AS DATE)'
                        WHEN @ColumnName = 'cust_name'
                           THEN N' @tosearch' 
                      ELSE N'' END

  EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlquery
                       ,N'@tosearch   varchar(50)'
                       ,@tosearch

   set nocount off;
end
```